# Why does Javascript's parseInt(array) work?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a simple array in Javascript like below, and calling parseInt on it actually does work. I was curious as to whether there was a simple explanation or if its just one of the oddity's of javascript.

```js
const arr = ['123'];
const res = parseInt(arr);

console.log(res); // 123
```

my best guess was that the array gets converted to a string ("123") and then parsed, but I wasn't sure how parseInt works under the hood.

Comment: `parseInt("123,456,789");`

Comment: Explained right there on MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#description

Comment: All JS built-in functions that only operate on strings automatically convert their argument to a string. So if you give them an array with a single element, it's like giving them that element as the argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [MDN's reference page for `parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt):

> The parseInt function converts its first argument to a string, parses that string, then returns an integer or NaN.

If we then look at the [MDN reference section on string coercion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#string_coercion):

> Objects are first converted to a primitive by calling its @@toPrimitive (with "string" as hint), toString(), and valueOf() methods, in that order. The resulting primitive is then converted to a string.

So let's see the result of calling `toString()` on `['123']`:

```js
const arr = ['123'];
const converted = arr.toString();
console.log(converted);
console.log(typeof converted);
```

It's just the string `"123"`, which, when passed as `parseInt("123")`, works as expected.

```js
console.log(parseInt("123"));
```

That said, being cute with automatic type coercion in JS is a dangerous game; it's *generally* better to be explicit.

Comment: "*being cute*"?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, the language there is a bit unclear; I should maybe update it.  I mostly meant some version of "being clever" and trying to omit lines of code in which types are explicitly set and instead relying on automatic type conversion.  There's certainly a few places where it can be done safely, but because the order of automatic conversion can be a bit arbitrary and unintuitive, there is often a risk for unexpected, difficult to debug issues.  If I recall correctly avoiding it is a Crockford recommendation in _The Good Parts_, but I could be misremembering.